# Browser logs out of sites on Ubuntu 22

Tags: browser, logout

I'm using Google Chrome and Brave Browser on my Ubuntu 22, and I have the same problem in both of the browser, that after turning off and on the computer I'm logged out of all sites.
I've already tried to clear cache, turn on the "Allow Cookies" e.t.c. But can't help myself.

Comment: Ubuntu 22?   There is no such release; are you using Ubuntu Core 22 which is closest being the *snap* only flavor of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server?  or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ? or Ubuntu 22.10 ?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. So I wrote just 22, is there a problem?))) I think the problem I described in my question is not about the version of Ubuntu.

Comment: 22 is a *year* product which is *snap* only; the *year.month* format refers to products of Ubuntu that can use *deb*, *snap*, *flatpak* & *appimage* products thus differ. There is no `apt install` in 22 only `snap install` being the specialist *snap* only flavor of 22.04, so your question currently relates to the *snap* only version of 22.04.  22 is a reduced function, but thus faster & smaller (better suited for cloud or appliance use) of 22.04 and not the same system.  Ubuntu has had *snap* only *year* products since 2016 highlighted by the different format of those products